# gwt Checkbox Text alignment

Tags: css, gwt, uibinder, gwtp

I changed the check box style in gwt, but the text is not appearing in the middle (Vertically). It appears on the top.

[image]

I tried to add padding, but that didn't help. Adding padding to the left works fine, but padding to the top doesn't work.

```
label {
    display: inline-block;
    cursor: pointer;
    position: relative;
    padding-left: 25px;
    padding-top: 5px;
    margin-right: 5px;
    font-size: 12px;
}

input[type=checkbox] {
    display: none;
    padding-top: 5px;
}

label:before {
    background-image: url(images/csscheckbox.png);
    content: "";
    display: inline-block;
    width: 22px;
    height: 22px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    /*border-radius:5px 5px 0px 0px;*/
}

   .gwt-CheckBox {
    padding-top: 5px;
}

.gwt-CheckBox label:before {
    padding-top: 5px;
}

input[type=checkbox]:checked+label:before {
    background-position: 0 -22px;
    background-image color: aqua;
    font-size: 12px;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 13px;
}

.agreement {
    margin-left: 5px;
}
```

What could be the problem?

Comment: what aint working? you have commented on your question ...i am not sure what you are refering to!

Answer (score 2):

Actually your CSS should target the CheckBox Label instead of the the Checkbox. So try something like this

> input[type="checkbox"] + label{   padding-top : 5px ;
>       vertical-align: top; }

Comment: What worked for me was  input[type="checkbox"]{
  vertical-align: middle;
 } 
 
 input[type="checkbox"]+label {
  vertical-align: middle;
 }

Answer (score 1):

This is a known behavior. Add the `vertical-align` `sub or middle` to the `label` (this depends on the label `font-size`)

```
label
{
    vertical-align : middle;
}
```

Another solution to not depend on the css and font size will be to seperate the `checkBox` and `label` in a table row (again some css to to keep it together :( but it will be one time and fool-proof) .

**EDITS :**

```
HorizontalPanel horizontalPanel = new HorizontalPanel();
horizontalPanel.setVerticalAlignment(HasVerticalAlignment.ALIGN_MIDDLE);
CheckBox box = new CheckBox();
InlineLabel inlineLabel = new InlineLabel("Option1");
horizontalPanel.add(box);
horizontalPanel.add(inlineLabel);
RootPanel.get().add(horizontalPanel);
```

Output :

[image]

**Normal Font Size**

[image]

Comment: You are right in terms of font size, but vertical align is not helping.. :(

Comment: did you try horizontal panel? it aligns perfectly in middle irrespective of font sizes the only pain is now binding them together via css as they can tend to take too much horizontal space.

Comment: @Bennet check modified answer it works perfectly! no need for CSS as InlineLabel is used :)

Comment: Yes, in terms of font size what you said is right. But, we cant simply increase the font size for this reason. it might look odd in the page. any ways now also it looks odd.

Comment: @Bennet that was just a suggestion. it works well with normal font size too. check edits...

Answer (score 0):

```
label {
    position: static;
    align-self: center;    
 }
```